# Unicredit February 2017: would I have Lost 50 Percent of my Money?

Tags: volatility, equities, risk

Some of the news regarding Unicredit indicate that the stock price was reduced by 50 percent from Friday (3 Feb 2017) to Monday (6 Feb 2017)

(e.g.: `"The share price halved yesterday compared to the closing price of Friday"`

=> `"Der Aktienkurs halbierte sich gestern im Vergleich zum Schlusskurs vom Freitag"`

see: Perspektiven am Morgen of Deutsche Bank, Germany, dated: 2017-02-07
(only availabe in German) - the web archive link is in my comment below.

I do understand it correctly, that the stock price in reality was *NOT* reduced by 50 percent, right? That is at least what Deutsche Bank states later on.

If I look at some of the stockmarket internet platforms, in the longer perspective, I cannot see this 50 percent reduction in their charts:

[image: http://www.onvista.de/aktien/UNICREDIT-S-P-A-Aktie-IT0005239360 - long]

in the short term, they visualize it as a 50 percent drop:

[image: http://www.onvista.de/aktien/UNICREDIT-S-P-A-Aktie-IT0005239360 - short]

What is correct? 50 % loss or only *"daily business"*?

Comment: Link to Deutsche Bank Website - archived: https://web.archive.org/web/20170207234616/https://www.deutsche-bank.de/pfb/content/pk-lp-perspektiven-am-morgen.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no.

Read the next sentence as well in the DB report: "The share price halved yesterday compared to the closing price of Friday. Adjusted for the value of subscription rights, it fell only by three percent.". So you would have received 'subscription rights' which would have compensated for most of the loss. The price charts are adjusted for this distribution (just like they are adjusted for dividends, splits, etc.) so they don't show the drop.

Comment: They're not normally adjusted for dividends though. Splits sure, but not dividends...